# Background image hover class works on Firefox but not Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help with my menu.

I have an image button class to my links, this includes `a`

```
.myButton:hover {
    background-image:url(assets/images/button2.png);
}
```

This image hover change does not work with the Google Chrome or Safari browser, however it works perfectly in Firefox!

Please can someone figure out why this is? And how I can fix it?

Here is the website (online temporarily)

http://zeendesign.co.uk/smiledental.co.uk/SmileDental/SmileDental/

Comment: please include the code in your post so future visitors aren't dependent on your temporarily available site.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're making the anchor `display:inline-block;`
Change the display to `display:block;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That worked! It's always something so simple! :)